# Integral inequality and trigonometry

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Show using the definition that $$\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^\frac{3\pi}{4} \sin^2(x) \,dx \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

> Definition: Let function $f$ be integrable on $[a, b]$ and $$p = \inf_{x \in[a, b]}f(x) \text{ and } s = \sup_{x \in[a, b]}f(x)$$
>
> now
>
> $$p(b-a) \leq \int_a^b f(x) \,dx \leq s(a-b)$$

Any ideas on how to approach this? I tried finding material on the definition, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is defined here? And what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: Hint: What is the minimum and maximum values of $\sin^2 x$ for $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq x \leq \frac{3\pi}{4}$?

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

We have $$\forall x\in [\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}] \;\; \sin^2(x)\le 1$$
and
$$\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{2})=1$$
thus

$$\sup f=1$$

Try to prove that $$\min f=(\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}))^2=\frac 12$$

Comment: I managed to find out that the $\sup$ and $\inf$ are $1$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ respectively. also solving the integral would also be approx $1.285398163$ and the inequality would hold, but could this be shown without integrating the function?

Comment: You do not need to compute the integral. you just use the double inequality that you wrote in your question.